# Using comma with a relative clause

Tags: commas, restrictive-clauses

Is there a ',' needed in this sentence?

> My chair which is broken is make of wood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have either two commas or none.

If you mean that it is specifically your broken chair which is made of wood, and you are not talking about any of your other chairs, then *which is broken* is **not** set off with commas: it is a *restrictive* clause, which tells the reader that you are only talking about that particular chair.

If you mean merely that the chair which is made of wood happens to be broken, then *which is broken* is a non-restrictive clause and it **is** set off with commas, like this:

> My chair, which is broken, is made of wood.